# VS Code still runs Java file even when build fails?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

Simple question here. Here is my Java file:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String []args) {
     System.out.println("It ran!");
  }

  void a() {
    qweifjew;
  }
}
```

When I press "Run" on VS Code, it says build failed do you want to continue? Makes sense since I have compile-time errors. But when I press continue, it is still able to run and display "It ran!". How come?

For more information on the run command:

```
C:\Users\jeffe\coding-tutorials\learning-jest> cd c:\Users\jeffe\coding-tutorials\learning-jest && c:\Users\jeffe\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.27.1\scripts\launcher.bat "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp C:\Users\jeffe\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\5e0a770d0910238b624ead6f98bca1ec\redhat.java\jdt_ws\learning-jest_f8aabfb2\bin Test
It ran!
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the decompiled .class file of your code:

```
public class Test {
    public Test() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("It ran!ddfseffe");
    }

    void a() {
        throw new Error("Unresolved compilation problems: \n\tSyntax error, insert \"VariableDeclarators\" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration\n\tqweifjew cannot be resolved\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh that would make sense

Answer (score 0):

You have *Auto Save* ON in VS code ?
It's able to run a previous successful build to give you an output.

Comment: I changed the print statement to `System.out.println("It ran!j;lkj");` and it printed `"It ran!j;lkj"`

Comment: Weird..!! very weird behavior for a compiled language.